# No parece todos los elementos del array en chartjs, laravel y vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]estoy desarrollando un sistema de ventas y estoy haciendo la estadísticas de cuales son los productos mas vendidos.
La sentencia ya lo pobre y funciona bien.

```
 public function __invoke(Request $request)
{
   $mas_vendidos = DB::select('
            SELECT v.idarticulo, a.nombre, SUM(v.cantidad) AS TotalVentas 
            FROM detalle_ventas as v 
            JOIN articulos as a 
            WHERE a.id = v.idarticulo 
            GROUP BY v.idarticulo 
            ORDER BY SUM(v.cantidad) DESC 
            LIMIT 0 , 10');


    return ['mas_vendidos' => $mas_vendidos];      

}
```

Luego obtengo lo que esta en el controlador mediante esta funcion

```
getMasVendidos() {
            let me=this;
            var url = '/dashboard';
            axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
                var respuesta= response.data;
                me.mas_vendidos = respuesta.mas_vendidos;
                console.log(me.mas_vendidos);
                //cargamos los datos del chart
                me.loadMasVendidos();
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

        },
```

Cuando la función `getMasVendidos` se ejecuta lo que hace es cargar los datos en el chart con la función `loadMasVendidos()`

```
loadMasVendidos() {
            let me=this;
            me.mas_vendidos.map(function(x){
                me.varTotalArticulo.push(x.TotalVentas);
                me.varNombreArticulo.push(x.nombre);
            });
            console.log(me.varNombreArticulo);
            me.varMasVenta=document.getElementById('mas_vendidos').getContext('2d');

            me.charMasVenta = new Chart(me.varMasVenta, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: me.varNombreArticulo,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Cantidad vendida',
                        data: me.varTotalArticulo,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero:true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
        },
```

Para comprobar que me esta estirando el nombre de los productos hice un console.log(me.varNombreArticulo); y me trae correctamente todos los nombres Ejemplo:

```
["Coca cola 500 ml", "Coca cola 1LT", "Ouro fino pack", "Tapa cuadril por kilo", "Costeleta por kilo"]
```

Luego cuando este array lo pongo en la propiedad label en el gráfico saltea el nombre pero me muestra igual la cantidad de veces que se vendió
ejemplo:

```
["Coca cola 500 ml", "saltea", "Ouro fino pack", "saltea", "Costeleta por kilo"]
```

Donde dice saltea me aparece en blanco, osea que saltea XD...

Ya llevo mirando un buen rato el código y no encuentro mi error

estas son las variables que declare en el data

```
varMasVenta:null,
            charMasVenta:null,
            mas_vendidos: [],
            varTotalArticulo: [],
            varNombreArticulo: [],
```

Al principio de la pregunta paso la captura de como se ve..

Comment: no sera un problema de que la grafica no puede mostrar nombres tan largos? probaste con nombres mas cortos?

Comment: pensé lo mismo y no fue por eso.. Le cambie el nombre y igual no mostró bien, lo que me acabo de dar cuenta es que tiene unas rayas divisorias de dos en dos y no debería ser así.. debería ser de uno en uno

Comment: interesante el problema.. nunca trabaje con ese control, asi que trate de ver si tenias algun problema de vue o de los array que se te haya pasado... si le mandas datos manuales, sin tanto ir y venir, se ven bien?

Comment: tengo un grafico estadistico para ver las ventas por meses y eso lo muestra bien,, y el código es el mismo a excepción que en la propiedad label le paso los datos directamente así..... labels: ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"],

Answer (score 0):

Era un problema de estilos... lo descubrí cuando estaba mirando la consola y cuando lo achique mas se mostró bien jajaja.. no se si reír o llorar.. esto fue la solución `<div class="col-md-8">, estaba así <div class="col-md-6">`